# Something like INotifyPropertyChanged when reading memory from unmanaged process

Tags: c#, winapi

I am reading memory from other running process which source code I don't have by using

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, uint size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

and everything works fine. I get the value I need, but now I want to implement something like INotifyPropertyChanged in my program, so when value in that unmanaged process changes, that my code registers it and updates my variable X.

So far I have

```
private string x;
public string X { get { return x; } }
....
Threading.Timer timerX = new Timer(x => UpdateX(), null, 0, 500)
....
private void UpdateX()
{
    //Read value from unmanaged process
    OnPropertyChanged("X");
}
```

which updates X by reading that unmanaged process memory every 500ms, but that feels like hacking. Also, memory in unmanaged process can change few times in 500ms or once in few minutes, so putting a less interval seems like overkill. Is there more elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? It seems you are part of the way there... see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: I know how to implement INPC when using managed code, but when value changes in other process, I want to update value in my process.

Comment: don't really understand this downvote, honestly. By me it's good question. The question is not about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (may be this is a mistake to write down this words), but the question how to implement notification mechanism like he wants in less resource consumption way. +1.        @user488819: I'm afraid you don't have other solution, in your case, then that one proposed by yourself.

Comment: @Tigran thanks for thumbs up. Yes maybe it would be better if I didn't use word INPC, but again I did put "something like INPC".

Comment: @user: In that case, you don't seem to really have any other choice other than to "poll" like you are already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to get a notification when memory in another process changes. If you were a debugger, you could use a CPU data breakpoint to hear about changes in a small set of places. But this would have a significant perf impact, and is only the right approach if you are actually debugging.

If the other process is something you own, then the best approach would be to disassemble and understand the code for other process, and add code of your own to send a notification. Working without source and making a small change is probably less hard than you think it is.

Martyn

Comment: The problem is I don't have code of that other process, but thanks for reply.